# How to find duplicate group records in SQL

Tags: mysql, duplicates, group

I have a table:

```
Group_ID Group_Creator_ID Group_Member_ID
A01 P01 J01
A01 P01 K01
A01 P01 L01
B01 S01 X01
B01 S01 Y01
C01 P01 J01
C01 P01 K01
C01 P01 L01
D01 S01 J01
D01 S01 K01
E01 z01 J01
E01 z01 K01
E01 z01 L01
```

I want to display the same Group_ID where they have the exact Group_Member_ID records.

Expected result:

```
Group_ID
A01
C01
E01
```

(because they all share the same J01 K01 L01 records)

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Please TAG your specific DBMS.

Comment: #phpadmin #mysql

Comment: what is the version of your mysql? Thanks

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks. phpmyadmin 4.9.10.

Answer (score 0):

I would group by `Group_ID` and assemble all values of `Group_Member_ID` into a list.

```
SELECT Group_ID
, listagg(distinct  Group_Member_ID, ',')
WITHIN group (order by Group_Member_ID ASC) as Group_Member_ID_listagg
FROM My_First_Table
GROUP BY Group_ID
```

[Link to SQL Generator](https://app.rasgoml.com/sql?transformName=%22aggregate_string%22&tableState=%7B%22tables%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22My_First_Table%22%2C%22columns%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22Group_ID%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22Group_Creator_ID%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22Group_Member_ID%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%2C%22baseTableName%22%3A%22My_First_Table%22%2C%22ddl%22%3A%22%22%7D&formState=%7B%22arguments%22%3A%7B%22agg_columns%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22column_list%22%2C%22cols%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A2%2C%22columnName%22%3A%22Group_Member_ID%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22Group_Member_ID%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%2C%22dwColumnId%22%3A2%7D%5D%7D%2C%22sep%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22value%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%2C%22%7D%2C%22group_by%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22column_list%22%2C%22cols%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A0%2C%22columnName%22%3A%22Group_ID%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22Group_ID%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%2C%22dwColumnId%22%3A0%7D%5D%7D%2C%22distinct%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22boolean%22%2C%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22order%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22sort_direction%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22ASC%22%7D%7D%2C%22transformName%22%3A%22aggregate_string%22%7D)

Once you had this, then you could query the unique combinations and then do the same thing...  get a unique combination and the `Group_ID` as a list.

```
SELECT Group_Member_ID_listagg
, listagg(distinct  Group_ID, ',')
WITHIN group (order by Group_ID ASC) as Group_ID_listagg
FROM Result_From_First_step
GROUP BY Group_Member_ID_listagg
```

[Link to SQL Generator](https://app.rasgoml.com/sql?transformName=%22aggregate_string%22&tableState=%7B%22tables%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22My_First_Table%22%2C%22columns%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22Group_ID%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22Group_Member_ID_listagg%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%2C%22baseTableName%22%3A%22My_First_Table%22%2C%22ddl%22%3A%22%22%7D&formState=%7B%22arguments%22%3A%7B%22agg_columns%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22column_list%22%2C%22cols%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A0%2C%22columnName%22%3A%22Group_ID%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22Group_ID%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%2C%22dwColumnId%22%3A0%7D%5D%7D%2C%22sep%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22value%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%2C%22%7D%2C%22group_by%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22column_list%22%2C%22cols%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A1%2C%22columnName%22%3A%22Group_Member_ID_listagg%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22Group_Member_ID_listagg%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%2C%22dwColumnId%22%3A1%7D%5D%7D%2C%22distinct%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22boolean%22%2C%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22order%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22sort_direction%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22ASC%22%7D%7D%2C%22transformName%22%3A%22aggregate_string%22%7D)

To tie it all together, I prefer writing with the style of CTE:

```
WITH CTE_LISTS AS (
  SELECT Group_ID
  , listagg(distinct  Group_Member_ID, ',')
  WITHIN group (order by Group_Member_ID ASC) as Group_Member_ID_listagg
  FROM My_First_Table
  GROUP BY Group_ID
)
SELECT Group_Member_ID_listagg
, listagg(distinct  Group_ID, ',')
WITHIN group (order by Group_ID ASC) as Group_ID_listagg
FROM CTE_LISTS
GROUP BY Group_Member_ID_listagg
```

You might consider tagging your post with the appropriate tag to specify what RDBMS you're using. I posted using Snowflake SQL so if you're using something different, the syntax might be slightly different.

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin mysql. 
I execute the above suggested script but failed of syntax error. Could you please help.  Thanks alot.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that, but it's just a matter of figuring out which SQL commands are not supported in phpmyadmin mysql and writing them differently.  I suggest you start a post with those tags exactly.... show the SQL in my answer and ask for help with phpmyadmin syntax. There might be experts out there who can help but I haven't used that flavor of SQL before. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate `Group_Member_ID` values ​​into a string for each `Group_ID`, and then select those `Group_ID` values ​​for which at least one other exists with the same `Group_Member_ID` value string.

For SQL Server a query can be like this

```
WITH group_members AS (
    SELECT 
       group_id,
       STRING_AGG(group_member_id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY group_member_id ASC) AS members
    FROM data
    GROUP  BY group_id
)
SELECT 
    group_id
FROM group_members gm
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM group_members gm1 WHERE gm1.group_id != gm.group_id AND gm1.members = gm.members
)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b59e04a251e0d6b3b0a419331486f8c8)

---

For PostgreSQL it can be like this

```
WITH group_members AS (
    SELECT 
       group_id,
       STRING_AGG(group_member_id, ',' ORDER BY group_member_id ASC) AS members
    FROM data
    GROUP  BY group_id
)
SELECT 
    group_id
FROM group_members gm
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM group_members gm1 WHERE gm1.group_id != gm.group_id AND gm1.members = gm.members
)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5fc0eae422ef4581f90619d1ff5d241b)

---

For MySQL 8.0 a query can use CTE and look like this

```
WITH group_members AS (
    SELECT 
       group_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(group_member_id ORDER BY group_member_id ASC, ',' ) AS members
    FROM data 
    GROUP  BY group_id
)
SELECT 
    group_id
FROM group_members gm
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM group_members gm1 WHERE gm1.group_id != gm.group_id AND gm1.members = gm.members
)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3bf0a4e57db46c8b8bf9230ff4e22b32)

---

A MySQL version independent query might look like this

```
SELECT 
    group_id
FROM data d1
GROUP BY group_id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(group_member_id ORDER BY group_member_id ASC, ',' ) IN (
        SELECT 
           GROUP_CONCAT(group_member_id ORDER BY group_member_id ASC, ',' ) AS members
        FROM data d2
        WHERE d1.group_id != d2.group_id
        GROUP  BY group_id
)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b162f6e09ca33b68d5fe04b9c597665c)

---

All queries produces the same results

| group_id |
| --- |
| A01 |
| C01 |
| E01 |

Comment: Thanks but right the line 1, there is a syntax error of "WITH". What's wrong? I am using mysql. Thanks for help out please.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @JohnnyChow, I have added a query for MySQL versions other than 8.0

Comment: I am on phpMyAdmin 4.9.10 of Qnap system.

Comment: Your old mysql version seems working now. Thanks alot. So, the WITH part is a new syntax?

Comment: @JohnnyChow, CTE was introduced in MySQL 8.0

Comment: I see. Some smarter syntax code?

Comment: Hi Alexey. The original record size is 120k. The result was around 1500 only. However, it got time out easily. I could only copy the first 500 reords. Is it because the sql code is too complex? Is there a better way to compose the code please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JohnnyChow, I suggest you upgrade MySQL version to 8.0 if you can of course. Using CTE in this case should improve query perfomance. See https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-improved-performance-with-cte/.  Also I suggest you to create a covering index on (`group_id` , `group_member_id`) so that subqueries use it during aggregation (I'm assuming IndexOnlyScan will be used).

Comment: Can't upgrade freely as it is from a company existing setup.

Comment: @JohnnyChow, I have updated the query for older versions of MySQL (it is version independent). Try it. And the index (group_id , group_member_id) must be created as it is being used (I checked).

Comment: index for 2 columns separately would help?

Comment: Instead of timeout 400, this time it timeout 504.

Comment: The separate index on `group_member_id` is not used in this case, only on `group_id`, so it does not make sense for this query. The covering index allows the engine to get the `group_member_id` values ​​for a particular `group_id` without reading the table data, so it will be faster anyway.

Comment: Ok. I select the index on group_id then.
I don't know what is covering index.

Comment: Are you saying:
ALTER TABLE FamilyGroup ADD INDEX index_name(`Group_ID`, `Group_Member_ID`);

Comment: Yes, also you can use `CREATE INDEX <index_name> ON FamilyGroup(Group_ID, Group_Member_ID)`. The only difference is that with CREATE INDEX syntax, you must specify a name for the index. Whereas with ALTER TABLE, you may specify a name for the index, but you don't have to.

Comment: OK. I did.
CREATE INDEX Group_Index ON FamilyGroup(Group_ID, Group_Member_ID)

Comment: Both your old and editted script failed due to timeout. I am sorry but I felt hopeless.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of timeout the query exceeds. You can try to set the "Statement Execution Time Optimizer Hints" for this query (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizer-hints.html#optimizer-hints-execution-time) if timeout failure is caused by MySQL settings. Just try `SELECT /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(2000) */
    group_id
FROM data d1 ...`. Here 2000 is 2 seconds of timeout allowed for the query to execute. Play with this value.

Comment: 2 seconds only??? It held for 15 minutes and then hanged.

Comment: Ok, maybe you should execute `ANALYZE TABLE FamilyGroup` to update the created covering index, if `innodb_stats_persistent` option is set to `ON` - "When the innodb_stats_persistent setting is enabled, run the ANALYZE TABLE statement for an InnoDB table after creating an index on that table.". And it's set to `ON` be default, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_stats_persistent

Comment: Also, time out, after I executed "ANALYZE TABLE FamilyGroup".

Comment: What is `max_execution_time` value in php.ini configuration file?

Comment: I don't know why the php.ini locates inside a test folder, but the max_execution_time has a value of 600.

Comment: I have another query to try. 
`SELECT
    t.group_id
FROM (    
    SELECT
        group_id,
        COUNT(group_member_id) AS member_count,
        GROUP_CONCAT(group_member_id ORDER BY group_member_id ASC, ',' ) AS members
    FROM data
    GROUP BY group_id
) t
JOIN (
    SELECT
        group_id,
        COUNT(group_member_id) AS member_count 
    FROM data
    GROUP BY group_id
) o ON o.group_id != t.group_id AND o.member_count = t.member_count`

Comment: `AND members IN (
           SELECT 
               GROUP_CONCAT(group_member_id ORDER BY group_member_id ASC, ',' )
           FROM data d
           WHERE d.group_id = o.group_id
           GROUP BY group_id
       )
GROUP BY group_id`

Comment: It looks weird, but the main idea is to get groups those have the same count of members at first and then compare them. In theory it would avoid aggregation of members for all groups every time when a new group is selected in the outer query.  But it depends of the query optimizer mostly.

Comment: Or maybe even so (replace the second part with following) `AND EXISTS (
           SELECT 
               1
           FROM data d
           WHERE d.group_id = o.group_id
           GROUP BY group_id
           HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(group_member_id ORDER BY group_member_id ASC, ',' ) = t.members
       )
GROUP BY group_id`

Comment: Some optimization yet  and finally `SELECT
    t.group_id
FROM (    
    SELECT
        group_id,
        COUNT(group_member_id) AS member_count,
        GROUP_CONCAT(group_member_id ORDER BY group_member_id ASC, ',' ) AS members
    FROM data
    GROUP BY group_id
) t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 
        1
    FROM data d
    WHERE d.group_id != t.group_id
    GROUP BY group_id
    HAVING COUNT(group_member_id) = t.member_count
           AND GROUP_CONCAT(group_member_id ORDER BY group_member_id ASC, ',' ) = t.members
)
GROUP BY group_id`

Comment: SELECT t.group_id
FROM (    
    SELECT group_id, COUNT(group_member_id) AS member_count
    FROM data
    GROUP BY group_id
) t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM data d
    WHERE d.group_id != t.group_id
    GROUP BY group_id
    HAVING COUNT(group_member_id) = t.member_count
           AND GROUP_CONCAT(group_member_id, ',' ORDER BY group_member_id) = (
               SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(group_member_id, ',' ORDER BY group_member_id)
               FROM data dd
               WHERE dd.group_id = t.group_id
               GROUP BY group_id
           )
)
GROUP BY group_id

Comment: @JohnnyChow That was the last try

Comment: Thanks a lot anyway. Time out. We ended up getting the correct result by a few sheets inside an Excel with formulas.

(The table has 120K records and failed.
But your code worked in a 10-row record.)